# How to getting string using a path to the element in SwiftyJSON

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, swifty-json

```
//With an array like path to the element
let path = [1,"list",2,"name"]
let name = json[path].string 
//Just the same
let name = json[1]["list"][2]["name"].string
```

In the documentation of the SwiftyJSON state that we can use a path to get the element.

```
    let displayLocationFull = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["full"].stringValue
    let displayLocationCity = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["city"].stringValue
    let displayLocationState = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["state"].stringValue
    let displayLocationStateName = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["state_name"].stringValue
    let displayLocationCountry = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["country"].stringValue
    let displayLocationCountry_iso3166 = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["country_iso3166"].stringValue
    let displayLocationZip = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["zip"].stringValue
    let displayLocationMagic = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["magic"].stringValue
    let displayLocationWMO = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["wmo"].stringValue
    let displayLocationLatitude = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["latitude"].stringValue
    let displayLocationLongitute = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["longitude"].stringValue
    let displayLocationElevation = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["elevation"].stringValue
```

I try to use a path to simplify the code, but I was unable to define a valid path.

```
let path = [1,"current_observation",2,"display_location"]
let displayLocationElevation = swiftyJson[path].stringValue
```

this is the path, error is displayed.

Anyone can tell me how to do?
Thanks

Comment: First, why don't you use: `let current_obs_loc = swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]`? Then, you just call for instance: `let displayLocationWMO = current_obs_loc["wmo"].stringValue`

Comment: The "1" and "2" in your first example are indices for accessing arrays. But `swiftyJson["current_observation"]["display_location"]["elevation"]` has no array in its path, so it would just be `swiftyJson["current_observation", "display_location", "elevation"]`. And of course, follow Larme's excellent advice.